# How can I get StackOverflow style timestamps with the DateTime class?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get a date that looks like this:

2010-07-08 23:59:59Z

from .NET's DateTime class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for the [universal sortable format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), like this:

```
string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
```

Answer (score 3):

See:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
```